# MongoCollection : Cannot update nested document

Tags: java, mongodb

I am trying to update the nested document

```
Document{{_id=59837be4324fb01040068109, idKey=2323, objects=[Document{{24889=Document{{key1=val1, key2=val2}}}}]}}
```

the json form looks like this

```
{
    "_id": "59837be4324fb01040068109",
    "idKey": 2323,
    "objects": [{
        "24889": {
            "key1": "val1",
            "key2": "val2"
        }
    }]
}
```

i tried to update as

```
String innerKey="24889";
mongoCollection.updateOne(eq("idKey", 2323),new Document("$set", new Document("objects."+innerKey+".key2", "val3")));
```

but then if i do

```
Document updatedDoc = mongoCollection.find(eq("idKey", 2323)).first();
```

i get

```
Document{{_id=59837be4324fb01040068109, idKey=2323, objects=[Document{{24889=Document{{key1=val1, key2=val2}}}}, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, ...
```

why did the object not  get updated? and why do i have the `null`s?

Comment: Could you please paste some valid JSON data? Your sample data appears to be more like a toString() version of your entities?

Comment: thanks, i added the json format above

Comment: does my update command look reasonable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access `objects` by named key (24889) so if you know the position beforehand you can try

```
mongoCollection.updateOne(eq("idKey", 2323),new Document("$set", new Document("objects.0."+innerKey+".key2", "val3")));
```

Better approach would be to  update your document to include keys. Something like

```
{
  "_id": "59837be4324fb01040068109",
  "idKey": 2323,
  "objects": [
    {
      "name": "24889",
      "value": {
        "key1": "val1",
        "key2": "val2"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

and use [positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#update-documents-in-an-array)

```
mongoCollection.updateOne(and(eq("idKey", 2323), eq("objects.name", innerKey)),set("objects.$.value.key2", "val3"));
```

`

Comment: You're missing a dot after the number 0 in "objects.0"+innerKey+".key2", "val3"

Comment: thanks! that worked. just a minor tweak, i had to use `Updates.set()`

Comment: by the way, is there a similar way for me to get the value of an inner key? what if instead of update, i just want to get the value? I tried putting the and filter in the `find()` method but it always gave me teh entire document

Comment: You are welcome. I should have noted that I statically imported the `Updates` class to use `set` method for your earlier comment. I don't think it is possible in first case but you can use something like for second case `mongoCollection.find(and(eq("idKey", 2323), eq("objects.name", innerKey))).projection(Projections.include("objects.$"))` and pick the inner value in  the application code.